# Heat equation solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, heat-equation

Given:
Heat equation: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau }=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$.

Initial condition:  $u(x,0)=u_{0}(x)$

Appropriate boundary conditions.

We assume that $u_{1}(x,\tau)$ and $u_{2}(x,\tau)$ are solutions.

Considering that $u(x,\tau)=u_{1}(x,\tau)-u_{2}(x,\tau)$, how do we check that $u$ satisfies the heat equation?
What is the initial value?

Answer (score 2):

Check the putative solution and see if it satisfies the heat equation:
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau}(u_1(x,\tau)-u_2(x,\tau))=\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \tau}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial \tau}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}(u_1(x,\tau)-u_2(x,\tau))=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2}
$$
but by assumption that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions, we have
$$
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \tau}=\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}\\
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial \tau}=\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2}
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial \tau}-\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial \tau}=
\frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial x^2}
$$
as required.

Finally, for the boundary conditions, note that 
$$
u_1(x,0)-u_2(x,0)=u_0(x)-u_0(x)=0
$$